# Update Cloud Run instance on secret update

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

On GCP, I'm using Cloud Run with secrets with environment variables from Secret Manager.

How to efficiently update Cloud Run instance when I'm updating a secret ?

I tried with this Terraform code, no success :

```
// run.tf
module "cloud-run-app" {
  source  = "GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-run/google"
  version = "~> 0.0"

  service_name          = "${local.main_project}-cloudrun"
  location              = local.region
  image                 = local.cloudrun_image
  project_id            = local.main_project
  env_vars              = local.envvars_injection
  env_secret_vars       = local.secrets_injection
  service_account_email = google_service_account.app.email
  ports                 = local.cloudrun_port
  service_annotations = {
    "run.googleapis.com/ingress" : "internal-and-cloud-load-balancing"
  }
  service_labels = {
    "env_type" = var.env_name
  }
  template_annotations = {
    "autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale" : local.cloudrun_app_max_scale,
    "autoscaling.knative.dev/minScale" : local.cloudrun_app_min_scale,
    "generated-by" : "terraform",
    "run.googleapis.com/client-name" : "terraform"
  }
  depends_on = [
    google_project_iam_member.run_gcr,
    google_project_iam_member.app_secretmanager,
    google_secret_manager_secret_version.secrets
  ]
}
```

```
// secrets.tf
resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "secrets" {
  for_each  = local.secrets_definition
  secret_id = each.key
  replication {
    automatic = true
  }
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "secrets" {
  for_each    = local.secrets_definition
  secret      = google_secret_manager_secret.secrets["${each.key}"].name
  secret_data = each.value
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick here is to mount the secret as a volume (a file) and not as an environment variable.

If you do that, point your secret version to the `latest` version, and read the file every time you need the secret content, you will read the latest version. Without reloading the Cloud Run instance or redeploying a version.